# Problems with getting the precompiled boost 1.44 to work with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost

I've been trying to get the pre-compiled Boost 1.44 to work with an empty project of mine. So far I have gone to property manager and set "C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_44\lib" in the Additional Include Directories but when I try to use: `#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>`
I get

```
1>.\Watchdog.cpp(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/thread/thread.hpp': No `such file or directory`
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: And add C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_44\lib to the library and executable directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add "C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_44" to Additional Include Directories, not "C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_44\lib"